# Is there any $p \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ with x and y degree both at least 1 such that $p(\pi,e)$ is known to be irrational?

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

The algebraic independence of $\pi$ and $e$ is a well known open problem, as is the specific case of rationality of $\pi + e$.  My question is if there is *any* polynomial with rational coefficients (other than the obvious ones where e.g. $p(x,y)=q(x)$) such that $p(\pi,e)$ has been proven irrational.

Comment: We know that at least one of $x+y$ or $x-y$ evaluate to an irrational when you plug in $x=\pi$ and $y=e$...

Comment: I do not think that there is such a polynomial. We know however that one of $e+\pi$ and $e\cdot \pi$ must be transcendental.